# IDE comment keywords

Tags: eclipse, ide, comments, rubymine, todo

So I only recently discovered the TODO comment. For those of you that don't know, most modern IDE's will recognize this word in a comment and flag the comment line a different colour so It stands out.

EG.

```
//Need to talk to Bill about refactoring this code

//TODO:Need to talk to Bill about refactoring this code
```

You may notice in IDE's like [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) or [Rubymine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) highlight the TODO comment and some nice other features to do with it.

My question is: What other keywords are there like the TODO? It seems like a much better way of communicating to developers through comments and a feature that should be a bit more widely known in IDE's. Their purpose is to help with development after all..

Comment: `FIXME:` works quite similarly to `TODO:` in vim.  Not quite an IDE, but still... :)

Comment: Can confirm FIXME works in eclipse too. Sounds nice actually. Thats 2 :D

Comment: Just a minor side note: leave the `:` from the end of the task tags. Many tools add them after the definition which is kind of a noise afterwards (esp. if some of the developers are using it, some of them not - for example, it messes up a bit the *Tasks View* in older Eclipse builds).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I can speak of Eclipse, you can customize it.

Click on *Window -> Preferences*, and search for *General -> Editors -> Structured Text Editors -> Task tags*, or for *Java -> Compiler -> Task tags* (there might be some additional ones like for JavaScript, PHP, StatET, etc.)

```
TODO, FIXME, XXX
```

I use some additional ones like:

```
CHECKME, DOCME, TESTME, PENDING
```

I personally like to use the `DISCUSS`/`REVIEW` tags just to make sure I speak about some issue with someone during a code review or pair programming (e.g., I haven't misunderstood the specification how something should work etc.).

You can also set the *priorities* assigned to the different task tags there too.

Comment: I added ASSUMES to capture non-obvious preconditions.

Answer (score 18):

These are known as `task tags`. In Eclipse they are `TODO`, `FIXME`, and `XXX`.

However, Eclipse allows you to modify the available list of task tags. Go to `preferences` > `Java` > `Compiler` > `Task Tags`

Here you can modify the available list of task tags, change their priority, and decide if task tags should be case sensitive or not.

Answer (score 14):

To add custom TODO tags in **IntelliJ** go to:

**Preferences > Editor > TODO**

Answer (score 1):

Patterns like TODO, FIXME are default in NetBeans as ToDo keywords. You can also add any keyword you want in Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Tasks.

Comment: I'm aware of this. I was just looking for a list of generally accepted ones or defaults in the indstry

Answer (score 1):

for enabling/disabling code formatter use:
// @formatter:on
// @formatter:off

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.2 for C/C++ the task tags are configured in Windows -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Task Tags.

You can also enable searching for task tags as @rlegendi answer.