# How to add code description that are not comments?

Tags: java, comments, todo

How do you add code description like Todo's or put a note in the code that is not a comment, i.e. "//" or "/* ... */""? Sorry for the basic question, I forgot the terminology and therefore cant find what it's called online.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586478/ide-comment-keywords) is most likely what you're looking for.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You mean like an annotation?

```
import does.nothing.Todo;

@Todo("Refactor this code")
public class Foo {

}
```

Comment: Ok, yeah, that's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the language provides what you are asking for, you must be referring to an ide-specific feature for the TODOs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about annotations. There is a stack overflow article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31822020/in-java-what-does-the-symbol-mean) on what annotations are and when to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are called task tags. It usually depends on your IDE if they are highlighted in the editor, or if there is a special pane which organizes your tasks.

Eclipse uses: TODO, FIXME, XXX (case sensitive)

```
//TODO
//FIXME
//XXX
```

IntelliJ uses: todo and fixme (case insensitive)

```
//todo
//fixme
```