# Is it possible to add custom task tags in STM32CubeIDE?

Tags: tags, comments, settings, stm32, stm32cubeide

I was wondering if one could define their own task tags (special comments like the default "FIXME" or "TODO") in the IDE? The IDE is Eclipse-based, but the preferences' window is not identical. So, the guides for Eclipse, like this one ([IDE comment keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586478/ide-comment-keywords)) do not work.

Answer (score 1):

I found it eventually at *Window >> Preferences >> C/C++ >> Task Tags*.